# How to add an image to a locked html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a big problem here. I want to add an image to html code. No big deal if only I had access to the html code. Unfortunately it's locked and it looks like that:

```
<ul class="cc-nav-level-0 j-nav-level-0">
  <li id="cc-nav-view-1691317785" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0 j-nav-has-children cc-nav-parent j-nav-parent jmd-nav__item--parent">
    <a href="/sound-packs/" data-link-title="Sound Packs">Sound Packs</a>
    <span data-navi-toggle="cc-nav-view-1691317785" class="jmd-nav__toggle-button"></span>
  </li>
  <li id="cc-nav-view-1691317885" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/apps/" data-link-title="Apps">Apps</a>
  </li>
  <li id="cc-nav-view-1691318285" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/comments/" data-link-title="Comments">Comments</a>
  </li>
  <li id="cc-nav-view-1701055985" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="#news" data-link-title="News" class="sub hide-lnk">News</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

The image I would like to add should be to the right of the font. Is there a way to insert the code somehow?

Comment: What do you mean when you say its locked?

Comment: @JoeyBreithaupt Hi, unfortunately I have no access to it because I use the website provider "jimdo". The code belongs to a template that I can change only limited. But I am able to add javascript codes and css codes to the "head".

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should be able to do what you want. Look at the jQuery commands: `.append()`, `.html()`, etc. For example:

Note that you can also inject new CSS the same way...

```js
$(function(){
  var newstuff = '\
  <style>\
  #new{color:red;}\
  </style>\
  <div id="new">Here is a newly-injected DIV</div>\
  ';
  $('#mt').html(newstuff);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mt">You can replace what is there with modified/enhanced code.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to link a script that inserts an element after the DOM loads. Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()  => {
  document.querySelector('ul').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div></div>')
})
```

Then you could use inline styling to make it whatever height, width and background you'd like:

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;background:url(yourImg.jpg);></div>
```

I made a quick [pen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/vQbEVa) to show you what it looks like.